# How is a question or answer is sent to First Question and Late Answer review queues?

Tags: feature-request, moderation

How are these queues maintained? It seems to be always empty whenever I get to them. Could there be a facility to notify the moderator with this right as soon as this queue fills up? Is it possible to explicitly send any of such items to the queues myself and then review them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How are these queues maintained?

Whenever a user with no existing posts posts something, it is sent to the first-posts queue. Whenever a user with less than 10 reputation posts an answer 30 days later than the question, it is sent to the late-answers queue ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177552/255554)).

> It seems to be always empty whenever I get to them.

Those queues are usually emptied rather quickly as posts need only one review to be dequeued. Also, late answers are rather rare: As of now, there were [only 806 such answers in the history of this site](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/stats).

> Could there be a facility to notify the moderator with this right as soon as this queue fills up?

If you mean that you are notified: If you reach 10 k reputation, there is a notifier in the top bar when there are more than three items in all review queues (taken together), which however happens rather rarely on this site.

> Is it possible to explicitly send any of such items to the queues myself and then review them?

There would be little point in this as there is nothing that you can only do from the queue (except for gaining badges). If you see a post that needs improvement, you are free to provide it without a review queue.

Comment: Great explanation. Seeing as you are not 10k rep. either, I suppose you don't get notified too, @Wrzlprmft?

Comment: I see this means that you'll be getting his feature in the German Language SE but not in Academia SE (yet).

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac: Correct, yet I managed to review [337 first posts](http://academia.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats).

Comment: Answer accepted. Does that mean that you are always on the lookout?

Comment: Not really. I have the front page open, so I see new posts. If they are older than a few minutes and matching the criteria, they appear in the queues. It’s often good to wait that time because often posters edit then.